# How to rename table rows by count, within a table with multiple classes

Tags: jquery

This is my setup, I have a table that is a part of a form, and there are a set of rows with multiple classes

```
<table>
  <tr class='class1'><!--all rows will host inputs and a button that can delete this row--></tr>
<!--the first row of a class will contain an add row button, and a set of headers-->
<!--there are about 4 rows for each class-->
  <tr class='class2'></tr>
  <tr class='class3'></tr>
  <tr class='class4'></tr>
<table>
```

rows of specific classes will be hidden/invisible to the user, until they press a button to display the table rows of a specific class. The user can add rows and delete specific rows by pressing a button. all the inputs have names, and should be generated automatically

However I want to keep naming conventions consistent, keep the range of names manageable.

I had developed a delete function, that accounted for the number of rows, and would rename all inputs based of its position, but this method only works on tables without classes.
here is what i had.

```
/*
inputs would look like this 
<input class="class1" name="input11"></input>
<input class="class2" name="input21"></input>
*/
<script>
$(".class1").each(function(){       
  var row_index = $(this).parent().parent().index();
  var newName = "input1"+row_index;
  $(this).attr("name",newName);
});
</script>
```

I thought about using a .count() command, but it would not provide the incremental naming that I want.

I want to prevent the situation that an input name be repeated and prevent the situation where there is a gap between input names
i.e. there exists inputs with the name: input13 and input15, but input14 does not exist.

Comment: You do realize that the elements are going to inheriently be indexed, based off of their position in their parent amongst their siblings?  And you can use the [jQuery nth-child](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/#nth-child1) selector to get a specific one, without the classes?  It seems like you're over complicating your code, and not using contextual selectors to their full potential

Comment: @Taplar, thank your comment, but i think you misunderstand my question. Because I need to find and cycle through every input with the class = "class1", and rename them as a part of loop structure so there are no inconsistencies.

Comment: I'm not misunderstanding that.  I'm suggesting that you do not need that at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the document's matching elements and concatenate the name with the index:

```
var z = 1;
$.each($('.class1:nth-child(n)'),function(){
  var newName = 'Name'+z;
  $(this).attr('name',newName);
z++;
});
```

Comment: You probably wanted to increment z here.